# Accessing PHP classes outside of namespace

Tags: php, mysqli, namespaces

I'm trying to extend `mysqli` outside of my namespace. Whenever I run it it can't find `mysqli` inside the namespace. How can I access `mysqli` outside of the namespace?

Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace xBell\Database;

class Database extends mysqli {
    public function __construct() {
        $hostname = \eBot\Config\Config::getInstance()->getMySQLIP();
        $username = \eBot\Config\Config::getInstance()->getMySQLUser();
        $password = \eBot\Config\Config::getInstance()->getMySQLPassword();
        $database = \eBot\Config\Config::getInstance()->getMySQLIP();

        parent::__construct($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

        if(mysqli_connect_error()) {
            \eBot\Printer\Printer::error("Unable to connect to the MySQL server! Error: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try `class Database extends  \mysqli`

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it! If you add an answer I will set it as correct.

Comment: Glad, it worked for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please update your code with following.

```
class Database extends \mysqli {

}
```

Comment: Will set as answer as soon as I can. Thanks!